# Shortest Path Between Q Matrix Cells

Tags: c++, matrix, graph, shortest-path

I saw this problem in a local competition and I am trying to solve it,

I am given a matrix with '**r**' rows and '**c**' columns. Then I am given '**Q**' cells,

My task is to find the shortest path: Starting at the top left corner '**(0,0)**' , ending at the bottom right corner '**(row-1,column-1)**' and travessing all '**Q**' cells . I can move either right, left, up and down.

Brute Force is out of option (has I only have 1 second of CPU time and I can be given at most 50 columns and rows).

Here is a Sample Input:

```
6 3   
3        
0 1    
4 2  
5 2
```

Here is the Sample Output:

```
7
```

I am thinking about some sort of BFS, but I have no idea how to apply it to this specific problem.

Any help or advise would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the shortest path between every Q and starting and finishing point.  Create a graph with these distances.

Since you can only move orthogonally, the shortest distance between two points is the sum of the absolute differences between their co-ordinates.

Select an algorithm to visit all nodes in your distance graph.  [Possible starting point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55221/408127)  Bottom line is that this has become the "travelling salesman problem" and you will need to decide which of the many available algorithms suits you best.

If I am understanding your input, the distance graph looks like this

```
Locations

B  0 0
Q1 0 1    
Q2 4 2  
Q3 5 2 
E  3 3

Distances

B  0  1  6  7  6
Q1 0  0  5  6  5
Q2 0  0  0  1  2
Q3 0  0  0  0  3
E  0  0  0  0  0
```